# transition opacity with delay

Tags: css, transition

I want to fade out an element after 3 seconds. I'm currently using an animation to do this but I've just learned of transition-delay, so I believe I may be able to remove the animation and do it through a transition. Is this possible?

My original code is:

```
.foo {
    animation: fadeOut 3s cubic-bezier(0.645,  0.045, 0.355, 1.000)
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    80%{
        opacity: 1
}
    100% {
        opacity: 0
}
}
```

Here is my attempt at a transition:

```
.announcement {
  display: block;
  font-size:22px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645,  0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition-delay :3s;
  opacity:0;
}

<div class="announcement">asdasd</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/vejewukusi/edit?html,css,output

Is this possible without adding another CSS class?

Just to make things more clear, I want to append a div with a class, wait 3 seconds, and then fade it out, and do this without using keyframes.

Comment: For transition to be activated you need to change the relevant property - opacity in your case. This means that you'll have to change opacity by assigning another class, or change it directly via JS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vovf4hdg/ any idea what I'm doing wrong? The delay isn't  working.

Comment: You're not triggering the transition. Add test class only afer rendering .announcement - https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/vovf4hdg/7/

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vovf4hdg/3/)? I have added an animation and a little function to animate the opacity:

```
.test {
    animation: opacity 1s;
}
@keyframes opacity {
    from { opacity: 0.5; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```